# Place an image on a image when a thumbnail is clicked

Tags: css

I have a code like

```
<a href='javascript:showImage()'><img src='/public/visit_images/img1.jpg' width=100 height=100></img></a>

<div class='orig_image' style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:181px; border:1px solid gray; margin-right: 1em; margin-bottom: 10px;display:none;">
  <div style="width:200px; height:181px; background: url(/public/shift-images/indicator.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;">
    <img id="caribbean" class="shiftzoom" onLoad="shiftzoom.add(this,{showcoords:true,relativecoords:true});" src="/public/visit_images/img1.jpg" width="200" height="181" alt="large image" border="0" />
  </div>
</div>
```

First I display the thumbnail image. When a user clicks on the thumbnail, I want the class `orig_image`, which is the original image, to appear over the thumb nail image. How do I do this?

Comment: Where is your `showImage()` function?

Comment: showImage function just 
function showImage()
{
$('.orig_image').css('display','');
}

Comment: Then post it in the question. The more relevant info you put in your question, the better the answers.

Comment: OK. Looks like the image will display. Your question doesn't say what the problem you are having is. What exactly is going wrong? What issue are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add z-index in your style:

```
<div class='orig_image' style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:181px; border:1px solid gray; margin-right: 1em; margin-bottom: 10px;display:none;z-index:999;">
```